# How do I disconnect from a cs:go match when the leaderboard is shown

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive

When ever the match is done, I for some reason can't find an option to leave the game. (Im new to cs:go btw). So how do I leave?

Answer (score 2):

Open Console using ` and type `disconnect` in the console.
More [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoRRnU_yTME)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to disconnect after the match is finished:

- Press <kbd>~</kbd> to open the Console Commands screen, type `disconnect`, and then you're disconnected.
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the menu and click the icon that looks like a power button.